# Actionscript 3.0 navigation menu

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a fairly simple flash website, the main page loads fine and now I am coding for the navigation buttons.  The first button(and all will function the same way) is menuBTN  I've created a scene specific for its loading animation called "menu".  I'm using gotoAndPlay(1, "menu") which loads the scene perfectly but when the animation runs out it jumps back to the "main" scene. I need it to play to the end and the hold until the user clicks another button.

The code I have is:

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;


menuBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuClick);

function menuClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1, "menu");

}
```

I've tried gotoAndStop(40, "menu"); but this loads the "menu" scene at frame 40 with no animation.

Please help and I love you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `stop();`  action in the last frame of the menu animation.

Comment: You are welcome. You can click the checkmark next to this question to mark it solved. Good luck!